# Wordpress plugin keeps dying

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I'm creating a plugin and i'm trying to use this code on the construct:

```
if(!isset($root, $version, $itemID, $codeKey, $authKey, $channelKey)) {
        wp_die('Missing params in $config for KM_Updates constructor');
}else{
    echo 'getting here';    
}
```

Whoever it keeps dying, I echoed everything:

```
$root = 'localhost/testplugin'
$version = null
$itemID = 1
$codeKey = '00000A'
$authKey = '123456789qwertyuio'
$channelKey = 1
```

Yet it keeps dying, even thou everything is set

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$version null will give you false on isset accordying to [official link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php).

null is the php way of saying 'this does not exist'. So set it to something else

Comment: Thanks! I got it out of the if and everything works like a charm now